# Check if any cells are merged within range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]I am trying to make program to plot activities allocation like the attached screenshot.

I succeeded to write the code but the only problem I have right now that I can’t check if the cells within a certain range are merged or not to avoid overlapping at the same row.

So if the code will plot activities from column 6 to column 9 in row 16 I want it dynamically check if any of these cells (cells within the mentioned range) are not merged and if the code found any of them merged it will automatically check the row below to avoid overwriting.

Solved. and the new working code is mentioned below, thanks for all

`

```
Sub Fill()

Dim lowrow As Long, lowrow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, x As Integer, w As Integer, f As Integer, m As Integer, a As Integer
Dim length As Integer, h As Integer, y As Integer, s As Integer

Dim length2 As Integer


lowrow = Worksheets("TA").Cells(Rows.Count, "Aj").End(xlUp).row

w = 4
x = 14
j = 40

Worksheets("TA").Range("F14:I69").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("J14:N69").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("O14:R69").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
 Worksheets("TA").Range("S14:T69").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("U14:V69").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("W14:X69").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("Y14:Z69").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("AA14:AB69").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
 
Worksheets("TA").Sort.SortFields.Clear
Worksheets("TA").Range("AJ7:AO200").Sort Key1:=Worksheets("TA").Range("AN7"), Header:=xlNo, _
Order1:=xlAscending

For i = 7 To lowrow
x = 14
For x = 14 To 69

        If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, w) Then
            For f = 6 To 28
                 If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 3) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(5, f) Then
                
                
                        If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 1) = "Power Off & Exclusive" Then 'Power Off & Exclusive
                        If IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                        For m = 6 To 28
                            If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 2) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(5, m) Then
                            h = f
                                If f = m And IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                GoTo theend
                                End If
                            For y = x To 69
                            For h = f To m
                            length = Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, h).MergeArea.Columns.Count
                                If length > 1 Then
                                GoTo nexty1
                                End If
                            Next h
                            For s = f To m
                                If IsEmpty(Cells(y, s).Value) = True Then
                                Else
                                GoTo nexty1
                                End If
                            Next s
                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).Merge
                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                            GoTo theend
nexty1:
                            Next y
                            GoTo theend
                            End If
                        Next m
                        GoTo theend
        
                                        Else
                                        For m = 6 To 28
                                            If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 2) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(5, m) Then
                                            h = f
                                                If f = m And IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
                                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                                GoTo theend
                                                End If
                                            For y = x To 69
                                            For h = f To m
                                            length = Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, h).MergeArea.Columns.Count
                                                If length > 1 Then
                                                GoTo nexty2
                                                End If
                                            Next h
                                            For s = f To m
                                                If IsEmpty(Cells(y, s).Value) = True Then
                                                Else
                                                GoTo nexty2
                                                End If
                                            Next s
                                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
                                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).Merge
                                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                                            GoTo theend
nexty2:
                                            Next y
                                            GoTo theend
                                            End If
                                        Next m
                                        GoTo theend
                                        End If
                                        End If

                        If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 1) = "Power Off" Then 'Power Off
                        If IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                        For m = 6 To 28
                            If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 2) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(5, m) Then
                            h = f
                                If f = m And IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 217, 102)
                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                GoTo theend
                                End If
                            For y = x To 69
                            For h = f To m
                            length = Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, h).MergeArea.Columns.Count
                                If length > 1 Then
                                GoTo nexty3
                                End If
                            Next h
                            For s = f To m
                                If IsEmpty(Cells(y, s).Value) = True Then
                                Else
                                GoTo nexty3
                                End If
                            Next s
                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 217, 102)
                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).Merge
                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                            GoTo theend
nexty3:
                            Next y
                            GoTo theend
                            End If
                        Next m
                        GoTo theend
        
                                        Else
                                        For m = 6 To 28
                                            If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 2) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(5, m) Then 'check end station
                                            h = f
                                                If f = m And IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 217, 102)
                                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                                GoTo theend
                                                End If
                                            For y = x To 69
                                            For h = f To m
                                            length = Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, h).MergeArea.Columns.Count
                                                If length > 1 Then
                                                GoTo nexty4
                                                End If
                                            Next h
                                            For s = f To m
                                                If IsEmpty(Cells(y, s).Value) = True Then
                                                Else
                                                GoTo nexty4
                                                End If
                                            Next s
                                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 217, 102)
                                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).Merge
                                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                                            GoTo theend
nexty4:
                                            Next y
                                            GoTo theend
                                            End If
                                        Next m
                                        GoTo theend
                                        End If
                                        End If
                                        
                                        
                        If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 1) = "Exclusive" Then 'Exclusive
                        If IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                        For m = 6 To 28
                            If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 2) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(5, m) Then
                            h = f
                                If f = m And IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                GoTo theend
                                End If
                            For y = x To 69
                            For h = f To m
                            length = Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, h).MergeArea.Columns.Count
                                If length > 1 Then
                                GoTo nexty5
                                End If
                            Next h
                            For s = f To m
                                If IsEmpty(Cells(y, s).Value) = True Then
                                Else
                                GoTo nexty5
                                End If
                            Next s
                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).Merge
                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                            GoTo theend
nexty5:
                            Next y
                            GoTo theend
                            End If
                        Next m
                        GoTo theend
        
                                        Else
                                        For m = 6 To 28
                                            If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 2) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(5, m) Then 'check end station
                                            h = f
                                                If f = m And IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
                                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                                GoTo theend
                                                End If
                                            For y = x To 69
                                            For h = f To m
                                            length = Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, h).MergeArea.Columns.Count
                                                If length > 1 Then
                                                GoTo nexty6
                                                End If
                                            Next h
                                            For s = f To m
                                                If IsEmpty(Cells(y, s).Value) = True Then
                                                Else
                                                GoTo nexty6
                                                End If
                                            Next s
                                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
                                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).Merge
                                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                                            GoTo theend
nexty6:
                                            Next y
                                            GoTo theend
                                            End If
                                        Next m
                                        GoTo theend
                                        End If
                                        End If
                

                        If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 1) = "Power On/Off" Then 'Power On/Off
                        If IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                        For m = 6 To 28
                            If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 2) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(5, m) Then
                            h = f
                                If f = m And IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Interior.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                GoTo theend
                                End If
                            For y = x To 69
                            For h = f To m
                            length = Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, h).MergeArea.Columns.Count
                                If length > 1 Then
                                GoTo nexty7
                                End If
                            Next h
                            For s = f To m
                                If IsEmpty(Cells(y, s).Value) = True Then
                                Else
                                GoTo nexty7
                                End If
                            Next s
                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Interior.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).Merge
                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                            GoTo theend
nexty7:
                            Next y
                            GoTo theend
                            End If
                        Next m
                        GoTo theend
        
                                        Else
                                        For m = 6 To 28
                                            If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 2) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(5, m) Then 'check end station
                                            h = f
                                                If f = m And IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Interior.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
                                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                                GoTo theend
                                                End If
                                            For y = x To 69
                                            For h = f To m
                                            length = Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, h).MergeArea.Columns.Count
                                                If length > 1 Then
                                                GoTo nexty8
                                                End If
                                            Next h
                                            For s = f To m
                                                If IsEmpty(Cells(y, s).Value) = True Then
                                                Else
                                                GoTo nexty8
                                                End If
                                            Next s
                                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Interior.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
                                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).Merge
                                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                                            GoTo theend
nexty8:
                                            Next y
                                            GoTo theend
                                            End If
                                        Next m
                                        GoTo theend
                                        End If
                                        End If


                        If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 1) = "Power On" Then 'Power On
                        If IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                        For m = 6 To 28
                            If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 2) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(5, m) Then
                            h = f
                                If f = m And IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                GoTo theend
                                End If
                            For y = x To 69
                            For h = f To m
                            length = Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, h).MergeArea.Columns.Count
                                If length > 1 Then
                                GoTo nexty9
                                End If
                            Next h
                            For s = f To m
                                If IsEmpty(Cells(y, s).Value) = True Then
                                Else
                                GoTo nexty9
                                End If
                            Next s
                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).Merge
                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                            GoTo theend
nexty9:
                            Next y
                            GoTo theend
                            End If
                        Next m
                        GoTo theend
        
                                        Else
                                        For m = 6 To 28
                                            If Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j - 2) = Worksheets("TA").Cells(5, m) Then 'check end station
                                            h = f
                                                If f = m And IsEmpty(Cells(x, f).MergeArea.Value) = True Then
                                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                                                Worksheets("TA").Cells(x, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                                GoTo theend
                                                End If
                                            For y = x To 69
                                            For h = f To m
                                            length = Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, h).MergeArea.Columns.Count
                                                If length > 1 Then
                                                GoTo nexty10
                                                End If
                                            Next h
                                            For s = f To m
                                                If IsEmpty(Cells(y, s).Value) = True Then
                                                Else
                                                GoTo nexty10
                                                End If
                                            Next s
                                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                                            Worksheets("TA").Cells(y, f).Value = Worksheets("TA").Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).Merge
                                            Worksheets("TA").Range(Cells(y, f), Cells(y, m)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                                            GoTo theend
nexty10:
                                            Next y
                                            GoTo theend
                                            End If
                                        Next m
                                        GoTo theend
                                        End If
                                        End If
                         
End If
Next f
End If
    
Next x
theend:
a = x
Next i

Worksheets("TA").Range("F14:AB21").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("F22:AB29").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("F30:AB37").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("F38:AB45").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("F46:AB53").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("F54:AB61").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Worksheets("TA").Range("F62:AB69").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium

End Sub
```

`

Comment: By *"it will automatically check the row below"* do you actually mean *above* since the value of merged cells is in the top-left cell? Could you share the relevant code so we could directly fix it? Also, *"the attached screenshot"* got lost somewhere.

Comment: please check now, I posted screenshots

Comment: You should post a screenshot of your worksheet and you should always copy your code as text. No one will type your code from an image to test it.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, this is the first time for me to post a question here, I have found a solution and now the code is working properly

Answer (score 2):

This function will test if there are any merged cells in a range:

```
Function RangeContainsMergedCells(RG As Range) As Boolean
    If RG.MergeCells = False Then 
        RangeContainsMergedCells = False
    Else
        RangeContainsMergedCells = True
    End If
End Function
```

You can call the function like this:

```
Sub TestMergedFunction()
    Dim RG As Range
    Set RG = Selection
    Debug.Print RangeContainsMergedCells(RG)
End Sub
```

To note:
The reason we are testing `RG.MergeCells` in an `If // Else` is because `MergeCells` Returns:

- True (if all cells merged)
- False (if no cells merged)
- Null (if some cells merged)

This way, our function function always return a definitive boolean value.

Hey Mohamed, the below is a version of the code you gave in the comments. this version works.

```
Sub test()
    Dim therange As Range
    Set therange = Range("E1:E4")
    If therange.MergeCells = False Then
        Range("D4") = "no"
    Else
        Range("D4") = "yes"
    End If
End Sub
```

It only works if you JUST test `= false` for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: As a side note, this function work well on your spreadsheet as well. You might want to just check from the sheet before running your script.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I did try that first, however, it looks like when `RG` is a range that contains both merged and non-merged cells, `RG.MergeCells` returns "Null". The extra lines make the function always return a definitive value - whether contains merged cells.

Comment: Fair call.  It would be worth explaining that in the answer.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Also a good call. Thanks. Will update. Increased quality of answers!

Comment: I tried .mergecells but it didn't work properly, below small sample that I have tried

Comment: Sub test()
Dim therange As Range
Set therange = Range("E1:E4")
If therange.MergeCells = True Then
Range("D4") = "yes"
ElseIf therange.MergeCells = False Then
Range("D4") = "no"
End If
End Sub

Comment: :-) That's my first *Null* encounter in Excel. How did you figure this out? I'd prefer a shorter name though: `HasMergedCells` looks quite nice since only ranges have merged cells. Also, shortening the code requires some *Null* caution: `HasMergedCells = IIf(Not rg.MergeCells, False, True)`. Feel free to use these in your answer. Finally, *Null* isn't 'Excel-redundant' in 'my book' anymore (I know about its use in databases). Thanks for making my day. Interestingly, the documentation states *"True if the range contains merged cells. Read/write Variant."*: `Variant`, not *Boolean*.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I had no idea how to solve Mohamed's problem, so I looked around the documentation until I found `.mergecells` along with some other similar properties related to merged cells. But i didn't find the documentaion to be too clear... so I just `debug.print selection.mergecells` in the immediate window to figure out if it would work.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I'm guessing it's read/write variant as you can likely use it to make cells merge.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I just tested it. Yes, you can use .mergecells to merge cells

Comment: @MohamedQasim I edited my response with a correction to your test sub